# Remove words not in database

Tags: java, mysql, nlp

I'm programming Java and using a MySQL database. Would it be possible to send a rather large string (+/- 500 words) to the database. Next I want it to remove ALL words that are NOT in the database, with this removing stopwords, misspelled words and other noise. After the shorter string should be returned. So all should preferably happen in the database itself

Is this possible in some way? The solution should be fast since I have +/- 6million strings like that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible and the implementation should be a trivial exercise.

Comment: I have never done this before so. Any help is well appreciated and will be rewarded :)

Comment: So no help from anyone?

Comment: What have you done so far to try to make it work? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: That's the thing, I know how to write a Java program splitting sentences in words than query the database to see if it's in there or not. Which is indeed a trivial exercise. But what I want is that the computation to take place inside the database itself. However, I looked up some things and it's possible with Hadoop and Amazon Elastic Database but for database containing several TeraBytes of data (which is too large for me). However, could this be possible in a MySQL database? If yes, I haven't been able to implement anything because I know nothing about the subject :)

Comment: If you just wanted to know how to execute code on the database then why not just ask that? Stored procedures are what you want. mysql calls them stored routines: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html I'm not sure what the advantage is in this case though, you only need to query the word list once.

Comment: Ok so, I have a MySQL database with my dictionary. Next I have files with text, I read in this file into my Java application. What happens next? Do I need to write small java code that splits up the text of my file into words and then query the database? (this is not what I want). I want to send the WHOLE text of my file to the database after which it returns text with ONLY the words remaining that were in my database's dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
                 //statement that checks to make sure user enters only letters
                 if(fname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
                 {
                    //updates 'Fname' field in db to text that user inputted in 'fname' textfield
                    rs2.updateString("Fname", fname);
                 }

                 //statement that prompts user if they enter something other letters
                 else
                 {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter first name in correct format!");
                    fNameTextBoxResults.setText("");
                 }
```

thats some logic, instead of using "fname" use your db name and check if selected words are contained in your db...